# Changing Row Height in a table

Tags: javascript, css-tables

I'm creating my first table using HTML and CSS.  I used a code generator to create the table "code" (HTML and CSS).  I add all of that to a long string and send it to MailApp.sendEmail to include the table in the Email.  It works great except that the report lines are too spaced out vertically.  I need help reducing the row height or otherwise reducing the vertical spacing.  I'd include some of my HTML and CSS but I can't figure out how to put in a format that this freak'n window will accept.

Can someone advise on how to reduce the vertical row spacing in a CSS table?

Comment: Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: kindly try to include code what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tr { line-height: 5px; }
```